# Как получить модель залогиноого пользователя?

Tags: yii2

Собствено мне это надо для того что бы использовать связи с другими моделями к примеру есть модель 
Adduserfield которая вот так связана с моделью User

```
public function getAdduserfeild(){
        return $this->hasOne(Adduserfeild::className(),['id_user'=>'id']);
    }
```

как мне можно получить поля из модели Adduserfield залогиного пользователя?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это же у вас релейшен в модели User

```
public function getAdduserfeild(){
    return $this->hasOne(Adduserfeild::className(),['id_user'=>'id']);
}
```

Вот и пользуйтесь им

```
$fields = (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) ? Yii::$app->user->identity->adduserfeild : null;
```

Answer (score -2):

Может так.

```
public function getAdduserfeild(){
        return $this->hasOne(Adduserfeild::className(),['id_user'=> Yii::$app->user->identity->id])->one();
    }
```